# Available Physical Memory

Tags: memory

There is a x86 process running on Windows Server 2008 R2, the heap in this process has 99% external External fragmentation:

```
LFH Key                   : 0x17fa3a27
Termination on corruption : DISABLED
  Heap     Flags   Reserv  Commit  Virt   Free  List   UCR  Virt  Lock  Fast 
                    (k)     (k)    (k)     (k) length      blocks cont. heap 
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
00580000 00000002   97344  85672  97344   1485   195    13    0    1d6   LFH
00820000 00001002    1088    260   1088     33     6     2    0      0   LFH
00ae0000 00001002     256    144    256      0     2     1    0      0   LFH
Virtual block: 02620000 - 02620000 (size 00000000)
Virtual block: 07380000 - 07380000 (size 00000000)
Virtual block: 06d60000 - 06d60000 (size 00000000)
003d0000 00001002   31616  15580  31616   1521   160     9    3      d   LFH
015e0000 00001002   15616   4084  15616   2266    43    11    0     15   LFH
    External fragmentation  55 % (43 free blocks)
01ed0000 00001002     256    160    256      1     3     1    0      0   LFH
01e10000 00001002     256      4    256      0     2     1    0      0      
01e80000 00011002     256      4    256      1     2     1    0      0      
01ff0000 00001002     256      4    256      1     2     1    0      0      
01dd0000 00001003     256      4    256      2     1     1    0    N/A   
01f90000 00001003    7424   2036   7424   1936   117     6    0    N/A   
    External fragmentation  95 % (117 free blocks)
028c0000 00001003    7424   2252   7424   1639    49     7    0    N/A   
    External fragmentation  72 % (49 free blocks)
02a60000 00001003    3328   2068   3328   2036    40     6    0    N/A   
    External fragmentation  98 % (40 free blocks)
027a0000 00001003    3328   1964   3328   1927    51     7    0    N/A   
    External fragmentation  98 % (51 free blocks)
02840000 00001003    7424   2400   7424   2372    41     6    0    N/A   
    External fragmentation  98 % (41 free blocks)
02980000 00001003    3328   1812   3328   1785    37     6    0    N/A   
    External fragmentation  98 % (37 free blocks)
02b70000 00001003    7424   2548   7424   2528    39     9    0    N/A   
    External fragmentation  99 % (39 free blocks)
02960000 00001002      64     16     64      3     3     1    0      0      
03e10000 00041002     256      8    256      3     1     1    0      0      
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The External fragmentation is mainly caused the 'released memory' of the 'free' is not constant instead of lacking memory.

Someone is suggesting adding more physical memory on this server, however to my understanding, the max VM address (even map to physical memory) for a 32-bit process won't exceed 4GB. From task manager, I can only see the Memory (Private Working Set) is only around 400MB.

I am trying to have VMMap result for this process. However so far, I cannot see a reason why increasing physical memory would help in this condition. Adding more physical RAM might help if working set is larger than physical available memory.

By the way, why a few articles suggest to look at private bytes of single process to determine if physical memory is enough? Private Bytes are what the app has actually allocated, but include pagefile usage; Let's say if the Private Bytes is large, adding more physical memory will stop paging part of memory?